# Why Location Permission Popup not coming after Reinstallation of iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am facing one strange issue while using CLLocationManager for fetching the current Location. When I request for current location first time I am getting the permission popup having **Allow** and **Don't Allow** options. I have choose **Don't Allow** and then I went to App Settings and Turn On Location by choosing **While Using the App** and come back to the app and Uninstall the app. When I Reinstall the same ipa file I am not getting  permission popup again.

**Observation:** When I was debugging the app I came to know that When App was installed first time and requested for Location Update I was receiving **AuthorizationStatus** = **kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined** and from there I was calling **requestWhenInUseAuthorization** but when I was reinstalling the app instead of kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined  **AuthorizationStatus** i am directly getting  **requestWhenInUseAuthorization**. I have observed this issue in iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 10. I have added permission keys into my info.plist file.
[image]

Please find the code snippet which i have used in the app.

```
- (Void)getCurrentLocation {
    // Check if location services enabled in settings..
        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
            locationManager.delegate = self;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Location Services Turn Off");
        }
    }

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo4An.png



    #pragma mark- CoreLocation Delegate Methods

        // This will be called when app level location permissions are changed.
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
        NSLog(@"didChangeStatus called.. status: %d", status);
        switch (status) {
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:{
                NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
                [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
            break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:{
                NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
            }
            break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            {
                NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied");
            }
            break;
            default:{
                [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // This delegate method will be called in case of iOS 6 or later when location data is fetched successfully.
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
        CLLocation* receivedLocation = [locations lastObject];
        [self formatLocationData:receivedLocation];
    }
```

Please check and Let me know what should I do to get the Location Permission Popup while Re-installation of same ipa file.

Comment: apple will ask for only once it will not ask for the permission even if you have written code once you have decline the permission after that you have to allow that app from settings

Comment: I also know that it will appear once per installation. When I remove the app from my iPhone and install again it should come again because it will consider again fresh installation.

Comment: @AnkitVyas Your understanding is incorrect.  A fresh installation will not reset the previous settings.  You're seeing that in your results, instead of kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined  you are seeing requestWhenInUseAuthorization, since that was the last value that you set as the user.

Comment: Yes I got the Answer.It is due to Apple's cache Policy.I have raised the Technical Support Incidents.Thanks @Chris Allwein and @ Rahul GUsai